# ¿Como soluciono este error System.IO.IOException: 'Entries cannot be opened multiple times in Update mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es acceder a un excel, crear una copia del mismo y eliminar de la copia determinados campos que estan en el excel original. Pero me salta el error System.IO.IOException: 'Entries cannot be opened multiple times in Update mode en la linea archivoHollistorCopia.Save(). Luego quiero guardar el archivo de copia y me salta el error en esa linea, estuve buscando y no encontre ninguna solucion, alguno sabe como puedo solucionarlo? Dejo a continuacion el codigo entero por si les sirve:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math;
using SpreadsheetLight;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace ConciliacionAutomatica_Prueba
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathfileOriginal = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "archivoHollistor.xlsx";

            string pathfileCopia = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "archivoHollistorModificado.xlsx";

            SLDocument archivoHollistorOriginal = new SLDocument(pathfileOriginal);

            // Crea una copia del archivo original
            File.Copy(pathfileOriginal, pathfileCopia, true);

            // Crea una instancia de SLDocument para trabajar con la copia
            SLDocument archivoHollistorCopia = new SLDocument(pathfileCopia);

            archivoHollistorCopia.SelectWorksheet("Sheet1");

            // Obtén las estadísticas de la hoja de cálculo
            SLWorksheetStatistics statistics = archivoHollistorCopia.GetWorksheetStatistics();

            // Obtiene el índice de la última fila con datos
            int indiceFila = statistics.EndRowIndex;

            // Obtiene el índice de la última columna con datos
            int indiceColumna = statistics.EndColumnIndex;

            int columnaConcepto = -1;

            //busca la columna Concepto
            for (int col = 1; col < indiceColumna; col++)
            {
                string valor = archivoHollistorOriginal.GetCellValueAsString(1, col);
                if (valor.Equals("Concepto", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    columnaConcepto = col;
                    break;
                }
            }

            int cantFilasEliminadas = 0;

            //existe la columna Concepto
            if (columnaConcepto != -1)
            {             
                for (int fila = 2; fila < indiceFila; fila++)
                {

                    string concepto = archivoHollistorOriginal.GetCellValueAsString(fila, columnaConcepto);

                    // Verifica si el concepto cumple con los criterios y elimina la fila si es necesario
                    if (concepto.Contains("Iva", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        concepto.Contains("Debito", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        concepto.Contains("Credito", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        concepto.Contains("Comision", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        concepto.Contains("Sircreb", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //borro esa fila del archivo porque no interesa para conciliar
                        archivoHollistorCopia.DeleteRow(fila, 1);

                        cantFilasEliminadas++;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de filas eliminadas " + cantFilasEliminadas);

            // Guarda el documento con las filas eliminadas
            archivoHollistorCopia.Save();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza "SpreadsheetLight y DocumentFormat" a la última versión estable y Compatible para el ambiente que estés trabajando, es decir:

Version Framework(3,4,4.5,4.8, etc)
ó
Net Core (3,5,6 etc)